# Django is not re-rendering css & JS via DetailView

Tags: javascript, django

I used inline formsets in the DetailView class.

```
class DetailView(DetailView)
```

In order to display the page correctly, I used the get_context_data function:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['formset'] = self.get_formset()
    context['question'] = self.get_object()
    return context
```

css and JS worked well on this page. However, I don’t know how to make the page also render well if the formset is invalid

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    [...]
    formset = self.AnswerFormset(request.POST, instance=self.get_object())  # create/edit an answer
    if formset.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(formset, slug)
    else:
        return render(request, 'questions/detail.html', {'slug': slug, 'formset': formset,'question':self.get_object()})


def form_valid(self, formset, slug):
    formset.save()
    return redirect('questions:question_detail', slug=slug)
```

If the formset is valid, then all styles and Java script work well. If the form is invalid, then the styles and script located on the questions/detail.html do not work.

I spent a lot of time trying to convey errors in some way to get_context_data, but I failed and rendered the page separately (return render(request, 'questions/detail.html', {'slug': slug, 'formset': formset,'question':self.get_object()})

Do you have any idea on how to render the page with form errors correctly? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you override `post` and `form_valid` methods indicates (to me) that the use of a `DetailView` is not the most appropriate. Why don't you use a `FormView` class based view instead? You can check [this link if you want to read more](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/).

It will bring definitions you need for `form_valid`, `post` etc without to override them.

Also, the way to override `get_context_data` is the good one if you want to add more elements to your context, so keep it that way if you want to access from your template to the object you wanted initially to display through your `DetailView`.

But because you have checks to do to your form, I would definitely use a `FormView` instead of a `DetailView`, then add what's missing via the `context`.

Answer (score 0):

If error, widgets from another form group are generated, so there are no more specific settings in them.

Comment: If you want to add precisions to your question, just edit the original question post, or comment it, instead of answering it!